# System calls made by KVM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kvm, hypervisor

Is it possible to trace all the system calls/Interrupt generated by KVM to interact with hardware. I know there are tools like **strace** which can trace all the system calls generated by any C program but how to do the same if you want to get all the system calls for a hypervisor.

Answer (score 1):

User space part (e.g. qemu) is a regular process, so strace will work for syscall tracing. Kernel-space part (KVM) may be traced via SystemTap or similar tool.